# Pasting text without interpreting as formula

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, copy-paste

I'm trying to copy a table of data from a website into Google Sheets. The table includes a column whose numbers are preceded by `+/-`, e.g., `+/- 33`. Excel works just fine, allowing me to paste in the table, and it correctly interprets the column as text.

However when I paste into Google Sheets, it interprets this as a broken formula, showing `#ERROR` for each column, and issuing a `Formula parse error`. Is there any way I can paste a table and prevent sheets from converting the text to formulas? [image: Example]

Sample source data to copy and paste to duplicate the problem:

```
+/- 1
+/- 456
```

Comment: Can you edit your source data to include a single quote (`'`) in front of each of those strings?

Comment: @ale I had actually mentioned that I tried that unsuccessfully in my original edit of the message but took it out because it seemed irrelevant. So no, that won't work thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can copy paste the data in a tab free of data in column `A`.
Then in column `B1` you can use this :

```
=REGEXREPLACE(formulatext(A1),"=",)
```

[image]

Copy the cell for every data you have in column `A`
Copy Column `B` then paste with the option `values only`

**Explanation :**
`FORMULATEXT()` is self-explanatory : it returns a formula based on a cell I.E. the string `=+/- x` here.

To get rid of the "=" sign, `REGEXPLACE` is a formula who can search for a string or a regex then replace it with whatever suits your need.
In our case we look for `"="` then replace with nothing.

---

*Why I didn't used `ARRAYFORMULA` to do this :*

`ARRAYFORMULA()` works for any function that takes a range (e.g. A1:B6) as an input parameter. Then it will also accept an array in its place.
Infortunately `FORMULATEXT()` requires a cell as a parameter.